# Calculate the Runtime of an Algorithm using Big-O Notation

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

here is the question:

```
for(i=1;i<=n,i++){

      for(j=2*i;j<=n,j++){

        puts("hello"):
       }
}
```

Here is my solution: the outer loop has `1+n+1+n` running time and the second for loops has `n*(1+n/2+1+n/2)`run times, and the third statement has `n*n/2` run times. the second and third statetment very confused me, i don't know whether my calculation is correct or not, any clarification would be appreciated, thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are allowed to use Big-O notation, you do not have to write down all the details.

Let T(n) be the running time of your algorithm when the input size is n.

First of all, `puts("hello")` is O(1).   As you can clearly see from the code, `puts("hello")` has been executed less than `n^2` times. Also note that if the outer loop was changed (reduced) to

`for (i = 0; i < n / 4; ++i)`

the inner loop will be executed for at least n/2 times for every `i`, that means the statement `puts("hello")` will be executed for at least `n/4 * n/2 = n^2/8`.

Now as discussed above, we have  `n^2/8  <= T(n) <= n^2`. Therefore we have T(n) = O(n^2)    (the analysis is tight, that means we have `T(n) = \Theta(n^2)`).

If you have problem understanding the concepts of Big-O and Theta, you may refer to this video: https://youtu.be/6Ol2JbwoJp0

Comment: how come the outer loop is reduced to n/4 times? i don't quite get it, could you please explained it more clearly. Thanks bro

Comment: yes i just very confused with the big o notation, so i have to do it the hard way. And i want to know whether my algorithm is correct or not?

Comment: also the "puts("hello") has been executed less than n^2 times", n^2 should be n/2 right?

Comment: Let T(n) be the running time when the input size is n,  an algorithm is said to run in O(n^2) , if there is a positive number C and a threshold n_0, such that whenever n is larger than n_0,   we have T(n) <= C * n^2.    Informally speaking,  an algorithm runs in O(n^2) means its running time is bounded by    C* n^2 for large input size.

Comment: "n^2 should be n/2 right?"  well for each fixed i,   "puts("hello") has been executed for less than n times", as we have  n different i, overall puts("hello") was executed for less than n^2.   To get the running time in Big-O notation, you need to figure out the "upper bound" of the running time. In our case  the upper bound is n^2.